# How could the company benefit from correcting a performance review

Tags: management, performance-reviews, philippines

Background:
My manager left the company before the semi-annual performance review was given. My manager’s boss performed the performance review and the review was vey low and the review comments are not consistent with what happened with the project.

I pointed this out to the manager’s boss and provided some email evidences, for example:

-Low rating for reporting the project as on schedule even when the project was delayed.

-Low rating for delivery since there where many extensions due to “ team fault”

In both cases, I provided email evidences that I reported the project was delayed and that the client admitted it’s their fault for the extensions.

Even with evidence, he(manager’s boss) decided to move the goal post of the performance review. That a lot of things happen after the client admitted it’s their fault and actually it’s “team fault” for the delay or that I am not communicating clearly both oral and written. Scope that I need to prove is much larger and vague.

With this, I’m planning to report to HR this issue, but I don’t want to sound self righteous or antagonizing. I also don’t discount  the fact that he might really have so evidence that he still not reveal yet. Or probably the manager that resigned didn’t give the full picture to him about the events with the project.  I also know that this would put a target on my back, but I signed a 5 year contract and simply cannot leave.

How can I report the issue to HR that I can show value in discussing the performance review and correcting it can give the company benefits too, like  I cna write better reports or can detect possible project delays in the future and mitigate tthe risk

PS. I am a total newbie in these sort of things.  Never complained in the  8 years of working(different companies) before.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere this is a new one. The manager resigned.  but still the same manager’s boss.

Comment: Please add a country tag. Handling this efficiently would be VERY different between, say, the US, Germany or India.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere at first we have an agreement on the type of evidence that is needed for the performance review. But after giving the evidence and he sleeping pn it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thanks. Yeah, I know it’s a waste of time. And I’m gonna get fired soon for “poor performance”. Might as well try complaining. Since I have never complained before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With this, I’m planning to report to HR this issue, but I don’t want to sound self righteous or antagonizing.

You should be very careful to judge if this is a battle you are willing to fight, get HR involved, antagonize a bit, etc.

Personally I don't see any benefit in escalating this further or insisting that the review is wrong. If you have evidence to cover your back, and you have done a good effort on the project, then you should be covered and not have to worry too much of being scapegoated.

Seems that the one responsible for this project was your former manager who left, and was the one who eventually should have been accountable for. If you pick up this fight I fear that some of that "blame" may be shifted to you.

Keep doing a good work. Keep documenting the emails, suggestions and warning that you see in current projects. If you feel that your job is in danger, I also suggest you update your resume and start job-hunting in case things really turn out that way (don't know the specifics of your contract, but I am quite sure that a 5-year contract does not make you impervious to being fired if they find a good reason to do so).

Comment: Regarding the contract, I don’t mean it like I cannot get fired because of it. There is a clause that states any training I received, I will have to reimbursed the cost, in case I got fired before my contract. I took a lot of trainings from my first two years. It’s quite a cost. Thanks.

Comment: @DexterBoyGenius Learning lesson: Do not sign another contract with those clauses ever again. makes your vulnerable and company gets an undue upper hand in retaining you for pennies (vs. huge repay for trainings).

Comment: @SouravGhosh definitely, it was a hindsight 20/20.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you start a war on something so miniscule as 1 bad review in the internym of bosses change?

HR visit will only paint you as a problem to be dealt with.

I would suggest to schedule a 1 on 1  with a new boss and set a topic of the meeting as scoring deliverables / expectations

This way you can understand what does a new boss base his scores, and, maybe, present status as a higher score than you got before